# Selenium - Trying to click several "Remove" buttons, but getting StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to remove several elements on a page by locating all of the respective "Remove" buttons and then clicking them.  However, I am getting a 'StaleElementReferenceException' as I remove elements from the DOM and not sure how to gracefully get around this.

Here is my code:

```
List<WebElement> removeButtons = SeleniumCommands.findElementsByCss("[id^=removeForm_]");
    System.out.println(removeButtons.size());
    for (int i = removeButtons.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        SeleniumCommands.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(removeButtons.get(i)));
        removeButtons.get(i).click();
        SeleniumCommands.waitClickById(ManageCommands.CONFIRMMODALOKBUTTON);
    }
}
```

Here is some HTML for the remove buttons...

```
<input id="removeForm_615" class="btn remove-task btn-danger" type="button" form_id="615" value="Remove" name="removeForm_615"/>
```

Where each removeForm has a unique ID after the underscore.

Is there a more efficient way of removing elements from the DOM in this way that will get rid of my StaleElementReferenceException in a for loop style or similar approach?

UPDATE:  This is the current edited code:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        SeleniumCommands.waitClickByCss("[id^=removeForm_]");
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        break;
    }
    SeleniumCommands.waitClickById(ManageCommands.CONFIRMMODALOKBUTTON);
    try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException ie) { ie.getMessage(); }
}
```

When I do this, I am getting a `TimeoutException` as it still continues trying to find something `By.selector: [id^=removeForm_]`.  How do I fix it so that it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` as expected?

For reference:

```
public static void waitClickByCss(String css) { wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(css))).click(); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make and endless loop, exit it when you don't find any more "remove" buttons:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        SeleniumCommands.waitClickByCss("[id^=removeForm_]");
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        break;
    }

    SeleniumCommands.waitClickById(ManageCommands.CONFIRMMODALOKBUTTON);
}
```

Please add an explicit wait if necessary.

Comment: Hey alecxe, I have this really close to working.  I do have a question, please refer to the original post for the update.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, to explain why I added the "click" inside of the `try` is because outside of the `try` scope, `removeButton.click();` wasn't working since `removeButton` wasn't guaranteed to exist.

Comment: @lmcphers sure, just catch the `TimeoutException`. Updated.

Comment: Thanks again alecxe!  I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Well, I thought that was nice and simple, but I'm getting a compiler error saying `TimeoutException is never thrown in the corresponding try block`.  Why would it say that?

Comment: @lmcphers okay, I am kind of rusty at java, but do you have that "throws TimeoutException" in the `waitClickByCss` definition?

Comment: @lmcphers also, check how do you import the `TimeoutException`.

Comment: Okay, I just had to specify it as `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException`.  It must have been referencing a different one.  Thank you!